# How can I use page.type() inside page.evaluate() in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm making a Facebook Messenger 'Bot'. I need to evaluate the last message sent to the bot, and respond to it. Listening to the new messages was straightforward, but how can i respond? I tried :`newMessage.textContent = 'Hi'` and then submit. but that doesn't work. And of course page.type()
won't work inside page.evaluate()

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the simplest solution but here you go)

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });

const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
      <input>
    </body>
  </html>`;

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  await page.exposeFunction('puppeteerType', async (text) => {
    await page.type('input', text);
  });

  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    await window.puppeteerType('Hi from page.type().');
  });
} catch (err) { console.error(err); }
```